# Load module configuration file from FS magnolia 5.7.9

Tags: magnolia

I need to understand under what conditions is a module configuration file loaded from the FileSystem (FS). Specifically I would like to know why is config.yaml file not loaded in the configuration?
Here is my `src/main/resources/<magnolia-module-name>/config.yaml`according to the file module structure described [here](https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/Modules/Module-structure.html) and [here](https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/Modules/Module-structure.html#_the_config_yaml_module_configuration_file).

```
'config':
  'gitRepoDirectory': '/Users/asusti/jGit/'
  'tempVersionDirectory': '/Users/asusti/temp/'
  'excludes':
    'green': 'green'
    'red': 'red'
```

I exported this config file as yaml from the module config and copied it to file location described above.

I also tried with a config.yaml like this according to the example [here](http://I%20exported%20this%20config%20file%20as%20yaml%20from%20the%20module%20config%20and%20copied%20it%20to%20file%20location%20described%20above.):

```
gitRepoDirectory: /Users/asusti/jGit/
excludes:
   green: green
   red: red
```

For testing this I deleted the `config content node` from the config app under `config/modules/<magnolia-module-name>` and restarted the magnolia instance. What am I missing?

I am running magnolia **5.7.9.**

UPDATE:

As suggested [here](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS57/Module+configuration#Moduleconfiguration-ConfiguringinJCRvsYAML) I added the config.yaml to `src/main/resources/mgnl-bootstrap/<magnolia-module-name>/config.modules.<magnolia-module-name>.config.yaml`with the following content.

```
'config':
  'gitRepoDirectory': '/Users/asusti/jGit/'
  'jcr:primaryType': 'mgnl:content'
  'excludes':
    'green': 'green'
    'red': 'red'
```

The config folder and the properties and node below do not install in config.

SOLUTION:
For bootstrapping I found the document [here](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/docs54/Bootstrapping) According to this document:

```
All bootstrap files are only imported once!

    Webapp-based bootstrap files are imported during the first run of the webapp when the Magnolia instance gets installed.
    Module-based bootstrap files are imported during the installation of the module.

If you want to import bootstrap files on every start up of the Magnolia instance or of a module, you must use custom installation tasks which are executed by the Module version handler or Module start up classes.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you are checking the wrong documentation. Please refer to 5.7 documentation from https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS57/

If I recall correctly, the feature is implemented from the 6.1 version.

And the page you are looking for is the following: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS57/Module+configuration#Moduleconfiguration-ConfiguringinJCRvsYAML

Notice the bean definition there.

Comment: The config folder and the properties and node below it do not install. Please see the update above @Ducaz035

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing 2 things. You can have bootstrap file in the yaml format (that's 1st and 3rd of your code smippets) and you can have module configuration loaded from the config.yaml file at runtime (that's the format of 2nd code snippet).

For the case of loading module config at runtime from yaml file, you should not need to delete whole module and force reinstall, you just need to delete `config` subnode in jcr once you have placed the `config.yaml` file at specified location. You will then not *see* config in the jcr, but can query it by code from the module class or see it in the definitions app.

Since JCR configuration overrides that coming from the file, as long as you have `config` node in your `module` node in the JCR, it will override values of properties coming from the FS.

Comment: Thanks @Jan what would be the right location for the module config.yaml in magnolia version 5.7.9? The only way according to this https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS57/Module+configuration is I guess bootstrapping using code snippet 3. I must be missing something since my module config file does not load from FS. I can assert  that, since I query it from the code and the code works correctly if I enter the config in JCR.

Comment: the right location would be so that in compiled jar file it ends up at `/<module-name>/module.yaml` but you are right that you can't use it in 5.7 to set properties of the module class and need still to rely on bootstrapping it to JCR (your 3rd snippet)